# Run Excel VBA script while opening a link table in MS Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have an excel work **"Pending Details"**, in that I have a sheet called **"Summary"** which is updated by running a macro in the same workbook. Macro Name **"refreshsummary"**.

Now the summary sheet is linked to MS Access as linked table.

What I need (wish) is each time I open the linked table in Access (Summary) it should go to excel run the macros, update the summary sheet and then that updated data appears in Access.

Please let me know if what am thinking is possible?

thanks in advance

Comment: Access and Excel can make each other dance.  in Access add a reference to the latest Excel Object Library and find some examples.  Here is one to open a worksheet: https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/access/open-excel-file/

Comment: You will have to do this manually through VBA. I'm not aware of any events that fire when a table is opened.

Comment: Use a form and code in its Open event.